# Is there any reason to *not* link?

Tags: tales-of-xillia

I've been playing around on the Strategy menu, now that I have a 4-person party in Xillia, and I notice that there is an AI option for "Link", which is "Always", "Often", "Sometimes", etc.

From my understanding, Linking allows access to both Linked Artes and allows passive skills to be shared (such as 5% hp, or 5% chance to stun on hit!).

In what situations would I want to use anything other than "Always"? Is there some benefit from *not* having a link?

Comment: Minor side note; If you happen to be playing with more than one player, linking with whichever character they are controlling overrides their 'manual' setting for as long as the link is active. This isn't much of an issue with 2 players (one AI for each to link with), but with 3 or 4, links should probably not be made except right before a Linked Arte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few disadvantages to linking.

- One of the main ones is that you share debuffs between you.  If one of you gets hit with something like Burn or Terror, the other gets it, too.  On the other hand, if one of you cures said debuff, the other gets cured as well.  So that basically cancels each other out.
- If you're playing with a friend, linking with them will override their controller settings, and revert them to AI control until you dissolve the link.
- Linking also tends to override support characteristics.  If you link with Elize or Leia, for example, the amount of healing they will tend to do goes down drastically.  Linked Artes will also override whatever it is they're doing, so if they're in the middle of Nurse, or First Aid, they'll interrupt that to cast whatever arte you do with them.

So most of the time, I tend to link with another melee character, like Alvin or Milla.  Their support spells tend to be rather minor, and you will still get some rather fantastic link buffs, and you can leave your support characters alone to focus on supporting your in-your-face fighting style.